# jquery create counter with value from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I am trying to create a script with jquery that pulls a number from a specified div (#counter below) and adds 100 to it every second and updates the number in the div. I've tried a number of things, but nothing with the intended result.  Any tips?  Here is what I have currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval("counter()", 1000); // run counter function every second

function counter() {
  var count = $("#counter").val();  // get value of counter div
  var total = count+100;  // add 100 to value of counter div
  $("#counter").text(total); // update counter div
}

</script>

<div id="counter">1000</div>
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FbJPY/

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Holy crap so many simultaneous answers! As I said in mine, http://jsfiddle.net/FbJPY/3/ is the working code.

Answer (score 2):

A few changes:

```
function counter() {
    var count = parseInt($('#counter').text(), 10);
    $('#counter').text(count + 100);
}

setInterval(counter, 1000);
```

1. Don't pass a string to `setInterval`. Always pass a function.
2. `.val()` is only for `<input>` elements. You need to use `.text()` (which will return a string), so you need to parse the text into an integer with `parseInt()`. The `10` tells `parseInt` to assume base-10.

Answer (score 1):

Edit - adding parseInt like others mentioned.

You're not calling counter() correctly and you should use .html() instead of val() like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(counter, 1000); // run counter function every second

function counter() {
  var count = $("#counter").html();  // get value of counter div
  var total = parseInt(count)+100;  // add 100 to value of counter div
  $("#counter").text(total); // update counter div
}

</script>

<div id="counter">1000</div>
```

Comment: `'1000' + 100 = '1000100'`.

Comment: Pass a radix to `parseInt` as well. `parseInt('014') == 12`, but `parseInt('014', 10) == 14`.

Comment: Why are you making a ***second function*** to call a function?? Just put counter in there!

Comment: Just figured out parseInt on my own and came back to see so many helpful answers to confirm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try casting count to an integer?

```
var total = parseInt(count, 10) + 1000;
```

Should use jquery html() as opposed to val() unless it is a form input.

```
var count = $('#counter').html();
```

Also noticed you are not passing the function reference correctly to setInterval()

```
setInterval(counter, 1000);
```

Comment: Pass a radix to `parseInt`. `parseInt('014') == 12`, but `parseInt('014', 10) == 14`.

Comment: @Blender good call - ECMAScript 5 specifies that 10 (decimal) is used as default, but not all browsers support this yet. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Yep, the latest Firefox doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
parseint($("#counter").html(), 10) // or ~~$("#counter").html()
```

and even

```
$("#counter").html(total)
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/FbJPY/3/

The issue is that your interval is not working, as well as you're not parsing a number from the contents of the div.

Fixes:

- Interval should reference a function, not a variable, so you can type counter without quotes.
- You need to parse the number from the contents of the div.

```
setInterval(counter, 1000); // run counter function every second

function counter() {
  var count = parseInt($("#counter").text(), 10);  // get value of counter div
  var total = count + 100;  // add 100 to value of counter div
  $("#counter").text(total); // update counter div
}
```

Comment: Pass a radix to `parseInt`. `parseInt('014') == 12`, but `parseInt('014', 10) == 14`.

Comment: @Blender Another thing, probably an issue with stack overflow for this case, if I try to put bullets in there it breaks the code tags - dafuq?

Comment: I did that, and it still breaks. You can try editing if you like